# How to expose Kubernetes Deployments as Services using the static external IPv4-Address of the Worker Nodes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openstack

I've set up a Kubernetes Cluster on a custom OpenStack Platform to which, I don't have any administration access. It is only possible to create Instances and assign Firewall-Rules to them. Each new instance will be automatically provided by a static external IPv4 Address which can be reached globally. This means, that I can't even create OpenStack Routers to my internal network.

So far so good, I've set up a Kubernetes Cluster using [`kubeadm`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/), `CoreDNS` and `flanel` as [`CNI`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/#network-plugin-requirements). The cluster Hardware Setup is as following:

- Kubernetes-Client and Server-Version: `1.14.3` linux/amd64
- All Servers run on Fedora Cloud Base 28
- 1 Kubernetes Master
- 5 Worker Nodes
- 6 static external IPv4 addresses (one for each of the nodes)

After the setup, I deployed my required services using `deployment`-files. Everything works as it should.

My question is now, how I can make the services externally accessible? Since I've no `LoadBalancer` provided by OpenStack? How is the best approach for this?

I'm asking this question after an estimated amount of four hours of Googling (maybe I'm just bad at it). I tried the suggested approaches from the [Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/), but it stays totally unclear for me, what the concept and the right approach for the task is.

For example I tried to assign external IPs to the Service by using for example

```sh
kubectl expose deployment $DEPLOYMENT_NAME \
                          --name=$SERVICE_NAME \
                          --port=$HOST_PORT \
                          --target-port=$TARGET_PORT \
                          --type=NodePort
```

or this

```sh
kubectl patch service $SERVICE_NAME -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["<worker_host_ip>"]}}'
```

Even if the external IP is now assigned, the routing to my destination service is still not routed properly, because as I get it, Kubernetes automatically assigns the hosts and random ports to the Pods (which is the desired behaviour), but with that in mind, every redeployment could crash the assigned IP to service mapping.

After your help and a big "Thank You!" in advance I expect, that I can assign the application ports of the containers, to the static IPv4 of one of the hosts and that Kubernetes automatically knows, that the deployed service will be routed over this specific IP even, if the Pods run on a different worker.

Comment: Are your services http based? If so, you can use an Ingress to provide routing to your services. The Ingress itself could be deployed as a daemonset, running it on each node. You would need some kind of external load balancer or DNS round-robin for your static IPs to be used to access the Ingress service itself.

Comment: If you have a NodePort service, it’s reachable on every node via some specific TCP port.  If you can configure routing rules outside the cluster, can you route (outside-IP:80) to (any-cluster-node:31234)?

Comment: @Thomas First of all, thank you for the fast response. As I've mentioned, I don't have the ability to adjust DNS, and Routing settings. I wouldn't like to set up for example an NGINX to service as a Reverse-Proxy only to access the basic services.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you too for your reply. As mentioned above, I can't adjust the incoming routing to the machines in this OpenStack. The bare machines are assigned with an IPv4 and a Firewall (no routing functionality provided) and that's it...

Comment: I really don’t understand the setup. Let’s assume it would not be kubernetes but any other application. How would you access it? Typing in the static ip you memorized or wrote down?

Comment: @Thomas Sadly it is currently the Case. I would be supposed to assign an A or AAAA Domainer Record to this specific IP-Address and access the application only in this way. So again, is there a possibility to create an IP-Pool in Kubernetes by using all the IPs provided by the hosts?

Comment: That is fine - you would then use the DNS as round-robin 'loadbalancer', add multiple A records for your service (one for each node) and deploy an Ingress. Based on the host name the ingress (inside) kubernetes will route the request appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

After a while of researching, I stumbled upon the [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) implementation of a bare metal load-balancing solution for Kubernetes.
This helped me to solve the issue described above.
However from my point of view, MetalLB should be only used as last chance, since it is not production ready and requires excessive configration using the NGINX Ingress Controller solution to properly map the IPv4 distribution of a cluster.

Anyway a big big thank you to the above gentleman, which were willing to support me and give advice!